# what should be the sourceCompatibility value in Spring boot 2.0.0.M6 for java9

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to create a basic application with,
     Spring boot 2.0.0.M6 
     java 9
as this is the version of spring boot supports the java9 but, I'm stuck with the value that should be used for sourceCompatibility in build.gradle  file.

I tried with,
sourceCompatibility = 9.0

But it throws an error on build, Could not determine java version from '9.0'.

Set up I did,

1) java 9 on the machine using Windows,

2) Created the spring boot application Spring Initializer with java version 1.8 
   as there we do not have java 9 in the drop down of java version

3) then Changed the Application configuration in Intellij which refers to java 9

4) In project structure, changed the project SDK to 9.0

M I missing anything, What would be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading the gradle version to 4.3 resolved the problem